# Fetching BLOB in Chrome Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I'm struggling to fetch an HTML5 video using xhr2 and blob responseType with Chrome on Android 4.2. The code works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox desktop and on Firefox Android 4.2 (with FF desktop, I use a webm video instead of the mp4).

```
// Taking care of prefix
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;    

// This function download the video
var loadVideo = function() {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.addEventListener('load', addVideoFile, false);

        xhr.open('GET', "videos/myvideo.mp4" , true);
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';

        xhr.send();
};

// this function sets the video source
var addVideoFile = function() {
    if(4 == this.readyState && 200 == this.status) {

        var video = document.getElementById('vid'),
            blob = this.response;

        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        console.log('video ready');
    }
};

loadVideo();
```

Can anyone explain me why this does not work with Chrome on Android? If I plug my phone to use the remote debugging, the console will display 'video ready', suggesting that the video was downloaded but it's impossible to play it, video is just a black screen.

Also, this code works if I use it to fetch images instead of video. Is there a limitation I'm not aware of, preventing to download Blob above a certain size? (My video is 1.5 MB).

Thanks you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is most certainly a bug.  If you get something that works on Desktop Chrome but not Android then 99.5% of the time it is an issue we need to fix.

I have replicated your issue http://jsbin.com/uyehun/1 and I have filed the bug too https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=253465

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to do this!

Answer (score 0):

Per http://caniuse.com/bloburls, for Android 4.0-4.3 you need to use window.webkitURL.createObjectUrl() instead of window.URL.createObjectUrl().

This will let you generate a blob url, though I haven't actually been able to get a video element to play such an url.